# Не работает Ctrl + c, Ctrl + z в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

```
a = input()
```

Когда запускаю программу на python в pycharm, то не могу закрыть её с помощью <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> или <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. При нажатии клавиш <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, просто копируется целая строчка. Система Windows 10

Я не могу даже обработать "except KeyboardInterrupt"

Comment: там есть кнопка стоп, сбоку

Comment: Знаю, но нужно чтобы работало с клавиатуры. Так как это странно, что даже если я в коде ничего не выделяю, то при нажатии Ctrl + c он всё равно копирует всю строку где коретка

Comment: А какая версия PyCharm у вас?

Comment: PyCharm Community Edition 2020.3 | 
Build: 203.5981.165 | 
2 December 2020

Comment: Ну из горячих клавиш для остановки программы вы можете `Ctrl + f12` заменить на: `Ctrl + c/z` через настройки. А еще помимо кнопки запустить, можно использовать в нем его встроенную командную строку

Comment: Я не смогу обработать "except KeyboardInterrupt"

Comment: Тогда просто нужно использовать встроенную командную строку в PyCharm, тут уже дело в привычке, к этому легко довольно привыкнуть)

Comment: @E1mir когда я имитирую запуск в консоли вывода, то по-прежнему не работает ctrl + c, а если я нажимаю ctrl + z, то в консоли отображается «^ Z». Я считаю, что это проблема консоли Windows 10, есть ли у вас предложения, как ее исправить?